# Can we combine two bindings with different condition?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

First for types inferences types which have attribute

```
 var _kernel1 = new StandardKernel();
```

Second -- which not marked with attribute

```
 var_kernel2 = new StandardKernel();
```

> It should be like , if we cannot resolve type in first kernel1,
>   resolve it in second kernel2

Bindings:

```
  _kernel1.Bind(a =>
  {
      a.FromThisAssembly()
     .SelectAllClasses()
     .InheritedFrom<IStepContext>().WithAttribute<MarkAttribute>(x => x.Type == Inheritance.Derived)
     .BindSelection(
           (t, baseTypes) => baseTypes.Where(bt => bt.IsInterface || bt == t.BaseType));
  });

  _kernel2.Bind(a =>
  {
      a.FromThisAssembly()
      .SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterfaces();
  });
```

> Example: (and this kind of classes can be a lot)

```
public interface IStepContext
{
    Type WhoIAm();
}

public interface IStepContextAB : IStepContextSecond { }

public interface IStepContextSecond : IStepContext { }

abstract class A : IStepContext { }

class B : A { }

class B1 : A { }

[markAttribute]
class B2 : A { }

class C : IStepContextAB { }

class C1 : IStepContextAB { }

[markAttribute]
class C2 : IStepContextAB { }

class D : IStepContext { }

class D1 :D { }

class D2 : D { }

_kernel.Get<B>() ==> B2
_kernel.Get<IStepContextAB>() ==> C2
_kernel.Get<D>() ==> D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should be like , if we cannot resolve type in first kernel1,
>   resolve it in second kernel2

I believe in this question what you are looking for is the [Ninject ChildKernel extension](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel):

> This Ninject extension allows that child kernels can be defined. A
>   child kernel is a Ninject kernel that has a parent kernel. All
>   requests that it can't resolve are passed to the parent kernel.

however, it seems what you are trying to get at is [conditional bindings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding):

```
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Ninja>();
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().WhenClassHas<ClimberNeeded>();
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().WhenTargetHas<ClimberNeeded>();
Bind<IWarrior>().To<SpecialNinja>().WhenMemberHas<SwimmerNeeded>();
```

Comment: it is good solutions if you have 3 classes like : Ninja , Samurai and SpecialNinja. But what if you have a lot of types which inheritances from IWarrior. 
?

Comment: like abstract class 1) A : Interface ; B:A ; C:A , D[Attribute]:A ; 2) E:Interface ; E1:E; 3) Iaa :Interface ; R : Iaa

Comment: take a look at `.WhenInjectedInto()` and `.WhenInjectedExactlyInto()` or `.WhenAnyAncestorNamed()`. otherwise please update the question with more specifics.

Comment: Look please on example which I have added. And you understand what I mean

Comment: As I understand , you have not understood my question and example ?

Comment: what is not addressed? if you want to resolve to Type with `markAttribute`, use `WhenClassHas<markAttribute>()`